# Amazon Alexa Account Linking doesn't work with Azure AD B2C

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, azure-ad-b2c

For two days I try to use an Azure AD B2C with Amazon Alexa for account linking without success.
Neither Alexa, neither ad b2c offer a way to debug and I can't see exchange between services.

Is there anybody who have succeeded to do this ?

**EDIT: Thanks to Saeed Akhter, I finally succeed in Alexa/B2C configuration.**

In AD B2C :

1. Create a app that represents my web app called by the alexa skills.

   - Include web api: yes
   - Authorize implicit: yes
   - Configure an App ID (`https://{tenant}/{myapi}`)
   - Save
   - Publish scope with a descriptive name and a value. The important label is the value and not the name.
   - Save
2. Create a second app for Alexa

   - Include web api: yes
   - Authorize implicit: yes
   - Response URL: set the two urls provided by Alexa
   - Save
   - Go to Api Access > Add > Select the previous API, select all and save

In Alexa configuration panel :

- Authorization URL: take the url found in `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={policy}`
- Client id: The application id of your Alexa app in B2C
- Domain List: login.microsoftonline.com
- Scope:

  - openid
  - `https://{your Alexa application id you setted in B2C}/{your custom scope value}`
- Access token URI: take the url found in `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={policy}`
- Client Secret: The secret generated by B2C for your Alexa app

After that, if you try the account linking from Alexa, everything should work!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not tried this yet and sorry of this is a rehash of things that you've already tried.

I was scanning Amazon's documentation here:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/linking-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system

It seems feasible you could get this working with Azure AD B2C issuing access tokens that are then accepted by your own web resource.  Seems like it would be ideal to get the Authorization Code Grant working if possible (instead of implicit).

You will need two app registrations:
1. Alexa App registration
2. Your Web resource registration

Within the Azure AD B2C blade, your Web resource registration will need to define a custom scope.  Your Web resource would need to access to that scope, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens#granting-permissions-to-a-web-api

It sounds like the Alexa App client_id (called Application ID in the Azure AD B2C App Properties blade) needs to be entered in Amazon's developer portal when you setup account linking along with the "scope value" you just defined in the Azure AD B2C blade (please don't use the "scope name" that's just a description of scope)

For the Authorization URL and Token URL you can find them by clicking the "well-known" metadata URL at the top of the blade when you open a policy in the Azure portal.  Inside the metadata document you will find "authorization_endpoint" and "token_endpoint".

Is this the path you tried so far?  Can you provide me any details on where it fails?  Does the login screen appear?  do you ever encounter an error?

Comment: Thanks a lot Saeed, you save my day!